# Soundcloud API: How to write conditions concerning dates/ids?

Tags: api, soundcloud

I'm having this use case I'm not figuring out by the soundcloud documentation page: I fetch the last 10 most recent tracks. In 2 hours, I want to see if there are new tracks. So technically, I want to ask "give me the tracks with created_at greater than the created_at of my last fetched track". How can I do that using the current Soundcloud API spec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send `created_at[from]` parameter in the request which will allow you to set a minimum creation date for your query.

For example
`/users/x/tracks.json?created_at[from]=2012-11-01%2016%3A02%3A00`

For more info check the filters heading underneath [each resource](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) :)

Comment: eheh, completely missed that :) Thanks.